# Obtaining weights numerically via a Fourier Transform

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, numerical-optimization, fast-fourier-transform

I have a particularly nasty function, f(x), and I want to numerically find the values $g_k$ where they are defined as the following.

$f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}g_k \text{exp}(ikx)$

I want to know the values $g_k$ for k from 0 to some large integer. I know this should be an easy question. But, I am not as acquainted with the Fourier transform as I would like to be. I would like to use the fast Fourier transform. Thank you for reading.

Comment: equation 26: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to calculate the $g_k$ analytically and are particularly looking for a numerical method. My hunch is that the best numerical way to calculate the $g_k$ for a poorly behaved function $f$ is probably a pretty deep research rabbit hole that might be difficult to summarize in a stack exchange post. The question may also be under-specified. Do you want a quick answer, a numerically stable answer, an answer suited to poorly behaved functions, etc.?

Comment: Right now I integrating to find these weights. But I assumed there was a method that exists that might be faster. I do not know $g_k$ analytically. I just know the function f(x) and am trying to find those weights.

Comment: By "analytically", I meant "calculating the integral $g_k = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-ikx} dx$. That will almost always be the fastest way to do it by hand if you have an explicit expression for $f(x)$ (other than using a table of fourier series). If you *are* looking for numerical methods you can code into a script or something like that, however, it looks like the perhaps obvious trick of estimating the integral above with the trapezoid rule behaves quite well. See: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~bremer/classes/fall2018/MAT128a/lecture8.pdf